# Cors Laravel, liberar apenas para um dominio especifico

Tags: php, laravel, rest, cors

Estou usando a biblioteca [LaravelCors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) e gostaria de bloquear todos os requisitantes exceto um Dominio especifico, como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se foi seguido toda a instalação [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors) vai na pasta `config` e abra o arquivo `cors.php` e no `array` de configurações, adicione o endereço na chave `allowedOrigins` como agora está no exemplo abaixo o endereço `http://www.teste.com`, ali pode também conter outros endereços, porque, aceita mais configurações.

```
return [
     /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
     | to accept any value.
     |
     */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['http://www.teste.com'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
]
```

Comment: Eu tinha pensado em fazer isso, mas referi ter uma posição mais segura... Vlw jovem. :)